# Cannot install Windows 10 after Linux (Arch)

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, partitioning, multi-boot, arch-linux

I want to install ***Windows 10*** next to installed already ***Arch***. I have two disks with partitions like this:

160GB SSD (sda):
    *sda1                                  /boot   ext4
    *sda2 dm-crypt with LUKS  /root    ext4

2TB HDD (sdb):
    *sdb1 LUKS on LVM                         ext4
        -/home
        -/var
        -/home/folder1
        -/home/folder2
    *free space ~450GB

When I was trying to install W10, i chose unnalocated space which was that free 450GB on HDD and i got output like this:

`"We couldn't create a new partition or locate an existing one."`

Do you have any ideas what i should do with this?

P.S. **There is no way** in deleting Arch, installing W10, and then installing Arch again. I spend too much time on installing Arch and configuring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing Windows after installing Linux (not just Arch, but any distribution) is not supported. The big problem is that the Windows install disk MUST see an MBR record (a Windows-style Master Boot Record), not a GPT (GUID Partition Table, the Linux-installed boot manager). ArchLinux discusses this on their Dual Boot Wikipedia page: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dual_boot_with_Windows#Couldn.27t_create_a_new_partition_or_locate_an_existing_one

You're going to have to wipe the Linux partition to get this done--there is no other supported option. The easiest way to do this is to boot to the Linux DVD and back up the Linux partition to an external drive.

ArchLinux has a Wiki page dedicated to the topic of setting up a dual boot computer: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dual_boot_with_Windows

Comment: But when i was installing Arch i set on my disks msdos partition table, so it shouldn't make any problems

Comment: It still has a GPT, which means the Windows installer will fail.

Comment: Could u explain me why it has GPT, if i chose msdos? And if it is like u r saying, there is no way with installing Windows without deleting Arch?

Comment: ArchLinux can set up a FAT32 or NTFS partition with a GPT partition table--that's not a huge issue, and the partition table is a separate issue from what partitions are on the desk.

Comment: Now, it MAY be possible to convert a GPT to MBR without data loss, but you run the risk of completely clobbering your drive. https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=623780#p623780

I've never tried this, and to be honest I would not risk it, but you may want to read it over and decide if that's what you want to do.